# Customizing ace-window to use letters instead of numbers

Tags: window

ace-window numbers windows for selection by the user (`ace-select-window`, `ace-swap-window`, etc.).

How can this identification scheme be replaced with alphabetic / alpha-numeric identifiers?

The rationale is: letters are generally slightly easier to type, so I'd like to use letters. *(at least before numbers; what kind of user has more than 26 windows open?!? :-)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [manual:](https://github.com/abo-abo/ace-window)

> ## aw-keys
>
> *aw-keys* - the sequence of leading characters for each window:

```
(setq aw-keys '(?a ?s ?d ?f ?g ?h ?j ?k ?l))
```

> *aw-keys* are 0-9 by default, which is reasonable, but in the setup above, the keys are on the home row.